# Consistent curves with dynamic corner radius (Swift)?

Tags: swift, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Is there a way to make the corner radius of a `UIView` adept to the view it belongs to? I'm not comfortable with the idea of hard-coding corner radius values, because as soon as the width or the height of your view changes (on different screen orientations for example), the corners will look totally different. For example, take a look at WhatsApp's chat window.

[image: chat window of WhatsApp]

As you can see, every message container view has a different width and a different height, but the curve of the corners are all exactly the same. This is what I'm trying to achieve. I want the curves of my corners to be the same on every view, no matter what the size of the view is or what screen the view is displayed on. I've tried setting the corner radius relative to the view's height (`view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.size.height * 0.25`) and I've also tried setting it to the view's width, but this doesn't work. The corners still look weird as soon as they are displayed on a different screen size. Please let me know if there's a certain formula or trick to make the curves look the same on every view/screen size.

Comment: Even if the project has been recently deprecated, you should take a look at [JSQMessagesViewController](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController) to learn how they did it

Comment: @nathan That's not really what I'm looking for. My problem is not specific to message views. I was just using WhatsApp as a random example of consistent curves. I need a solution for ALL `UIView` subclasses (image views, text views, buttons, etc.). I'm not creating a chat application, and even if I were, I'd be capable of creating my own message views without including that Github project. I just need the corners to stay the same on different orientations.

Comment: What you either haven't noticed or failed to mention (if you did notice) is that in your example there is also a considerable *straight* border between each corner. That's the important thing, as cornerRadius only impacts the corners - meaning if your view/subview is so small you end up with a circle (no room for a straight border) you need to make the corner radius value smaller. The *max* value for a corner radius - which results in a circle - is frame height or width divided by two. Maybe you could use that rule of thumb to decide what value you want.

Comment: @dfd I did notice that and I did know everything you explained to me. Here's the trick though: because of the many screen sizes on which the width and the height of the screen don't always stay in the same aspect ratio (ex.: iPhone 4s and iPhone 5s have the same width, but not the same height), to the best of my knowledge, I have no way of determining which attribute I'm supposed to relate the corner radius to. What the curve of a certain corner radius value looks like, depends on BOTH the width AND the height of a view, correct?

Comment: @dfd I can set the cornerRadius relative to the width (radius = width x 0.1), but if the height of that view were to increase the curves of the view would also start to change (which is exactly what happens when a view needs to be displayed on both a 4s screen AND a 5s screen).

Comment: My thinking is that *only* if you are working with extremely small view sizes - say too small for readable text - you shouldn't need to worry. (1) Use auto layout to make it easy to code/layout for all screen sizes, then (2) set the corner radius. If you have a deeply nested view hierarchy, set [at most] two things - the corner radius and the nested limit. EDIT: I just saw your latest comment. Could you give me some specifics? Something I can duplicate fairly quickly? I'm likely going offline for 6 hours so my next reply may be tomorrow morning (it's 4pm here).

Comment: @dfd The most common example of corner radius issues I run into, are usually with views which have a big width/height ratio. Think of something like a width of 100 and a height of 10. Say I would hard-code the corner radius to 10, that means my corner radius is 0,1 x the view's width. On a different screen size the width of that same view could be 80, and with the same hard-coded corner radius of 10, the radius would now be 0,125 x the view's width, which means it got slightly closer to the maximum value of 0,5 x the view's width, at which the view is completely rounded.

Comment: @dfd This might not be the best example, since the corner radius difference is so small you probably wouldn't be able to see it with the naked eye, but I hope you can see from this example that the width of a view influences the outputted curve of a hard-corded corner radius. The smaller the width gets, the bigger the curve becomes. And this can be done with the height of the view as well. To make it even more complicated: with huge width and height ratios like the example I gave you, it's a lot harder to set a proper corner radius (corner radius of 10 means it would be 1x the view's height).

Comment: @dfd That means it would be well beyond the 0,5 x height maximum, which results in a very ugly pointy corner halfway through the vertical border of the view. I think it should be theoretically possible to make the corner radius value so dynamic, that it would adept to BOTH the height and the width of the view. The corner radius value would have to constantly change depending on whichever layout attribute (width or height) has changed. I'm looking for a formula to calculate this, but it's a little more complicated than a view basic math equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the best I can do. I don't know if this will be of help, but hopefully it will give you some ideas.

**First the code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let cornerRadius:CGFloat = 10
    let insetValue:CGFloat = 10
    var numberOfViews:Int = 0
    var myViews = [UIView]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        setNumberOfViews()
        createViews()
        createViewHierarchy()
        addConstraints()
    }

    func setNumberOfViews() {
        var smallerDimension:CGFloat = 0
        if view.frame.height < view.frame.width {
            smallerDimension = view.frame.height
        } else {
            smallerDimension = view.frame.width
        }
        let viewCount = smallerDimension / (insetValue * 2)
        numberOfViews = Int(viewCount)
    }

    func createViews() {
        for i in 1...numberOfViews {
            switch i % 5 {
            case 0:
                myViews.append(MyView(UIColor.black, cornerRadius))
            case 1:
                myViews.append(MyView(UIColor.blue, cornerRadius))
            case 2:
                myViews.append(MyView(UIColor.red, cornerRadius))
            case 3:
                myViews.append(MyView(UIColor.yellow, cornerRadius))
            case 4:
                myViews.append(MyView(UIColor.green, cornerRadius))
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func createViewHierarchy() {
        view.addSubview(myViews[0])
        for i in 1...myViews.count-1 {
            myViews[i-1].addSubview(myViews[i])
        }
    }

    func addConstraints() {
        for view in myViews {
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (view.superview?.topAnchor)!, constant: insetValue).isActive = true
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (view.superview?.leadingAnchor)!, constant: insetValue).isActive = true
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (view.superview?.trailingAnchor)!, constant: -insetValue).isActive = true
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (view.superview?.bottomAnchor)!, constant: -insetValue).isActive = true
        }
    }
}

class MyView: UIView {
    convenience init(_ backgroundColor:UIColor, _ cornerRadius:CGFloat) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

This is fairly simple code. The intent was to create as deeply nested a view hierarchy as possible, and, using auto layout, have two main variables: `cornerRadius` (the view's corner radius) and `insetValue` (the "frame's" inset). These two variables can be adjusted for experimenting.

The bulk of the logic is in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, where the root view frame size is know. Since I'm using 5 different background colors, I'm calculating how many views can fit in the hierarchy. Then I'm creating them, followed by creating the view hierarchy, and finally I'm adding the constraints.

**Experimenting and conclusions:**

- I was able to see what your concern is - yes, if a view's size components are smaller than the corner radius, you end up with inconsistent looking corners. But these values are pretty small - pretty much 10 or less. Most views are unusable at that size. (If I recall even the HIG suggests that a button should be no less than 40 points in size. Sure, even Apple breaks that rule. Still.)
- If your 'insetValue`is sufficiently larger than the corner radius, you should never have an issue. Likewise, using the iMessage scenario, a single`UILabel`containing text and/or emoticons should have enough height that a noticeable`cornerRadius` can be had.
- The key point to set things like `cornerRadius` and `insetValue` is in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, when you can decide (1) which is the smaller dimension, height or width, (2) how deeply you can nest views, and (3) how large of a corner radius you can set.
- Use auto layout! Please note the absolute lack of frames. Other than determining the root view's dimensions at the appropriate time, you can write very compact code without worrying about device size or orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Setting the corner radius in `viewWillLayoutSubviews()` was definitly the most useful tip. I did not know that. I'll definitly give the above code a try. The outcome should be better than anything I've tried so far.

Comment: What would be the equivalent for a UIButon object? (because there is no such viewWillLayoutSubviews() for it)
I tried to play with: 1) awakeFromNib()  but it is not dynamic
2) layerWillDraw()  doesn't do a thing

Comment: This is a pretty old answer, so I needed to read through it! :-) The base class I worked with is a `UIViewController`, not `UIView`. I think that's *the* basic difference. Obviously my first thought is "Can you move the code to the view controller?". But if not, my next thought is can you code against `layoutSubviews`? My concern there is two-fold: (1) Will the OS automatically kick it off - and at the right time? (2) How do you time kicking it off in the view controller via `setNeedsLayout`?